# React: Execute the latter part of the function only after the first part is fully completed

Tags: reactjs, callback, promise, redux

I have a function fetchTweets that fetches tweets with given parameters a and b.

Function toPageTwo calls fetchTweets function and then redirects user to another page where the fetched data is being shown

```
toPageTwo() {
      this.fetchTweets(param1,param2);
      this.props.router.push(`/page2`);
    }
}
```

toPageTwo() is being executed when user click a send button:

```
<Button onClick={::this.toPageTwo}>
Send
</Button>
```

How could I ensure that page2 is loaded only after the tweets are properly fetched?

UPDATE:

I'm using Redux and Axios to fetch the tweets and the button that starts the fetching etc is located in the sidebar. My file tree looks like this:

```
src
  redux
    actions
      tweets.js
  common
    sidebar.js
```

tweets.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

export function fetchTweets(a,b){
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/?a="+a+"&b="+b)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_REJECTED", payload: err})
        })
    }
}
```

If I add ".then" to FETCH_TWEETS_FULFILLED dispatch, I'm able to console log after fetching. However this does not work with this.props.router.push(`/page2`)

sidebar.js:

```
-- IMPORTS --
@connect((state) => state)

@withRouter
class ApplicationSidebar extends React.Component {

    -- BUNCH OF FUNCTIONS --

    fetchTweets(a,b) {
      this.props.dispatch(fetchTweets(a,b));
    }

    toPageTwo() {
          fetchTweets(param_a,param_b);
          this.props.router.push(`/page2`);
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            -- SIDEBAR STUFF --

                <Button onClick={::this.toPageTwo}>
                Send
                </Button>

        );
     }
```

For some reason creating a callback function results the same result as regular function: the latter function is being executed before the first part (tweet fetching) is completed.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you fetching tweets?

Comment: I added more stuff to my original post. Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion: tag your question with redux tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think modifying `fetchTweets` to take a callback would be the best way to do this.

eg.

```
import axios from "axios";

export function fetchTweets(a,b, callback){
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/?a="+a+"&b="+b)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
            callback()
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_REJECTED", payload: err})
        })
    }
}
```

and

```
-- IMPORTS --
@connect((state) => state)

@withRouter
class ApplicationSidebar extends React.Component {

-- BUNCH OF FUNCTIONS --

    fetchTweets(a,b, callback) {
      this.props.dispatch(fetchTweets(a,b, callback));
    }
```

Now here is where you pass an anonymous function as the callback, eg.

```
    toPageTwo() {
          fetchTweets(param_a,param_b, () => {this.props.router.push(`/page2`));
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            -- SIDEBAR STUFF --

                <Button onClick={::this.toPageTwo}>
                Send
                </Button>

        );
     }
```

Comment: For some reason the callback function results the same result as regular function. I added information to my original post. Thanks!

Comment: @jjjayn I have updated my comment to reflect your updated code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if and a Boolean, i.e:

```
toPageTwo() 
{
   if( fetchTweets(param1,param2) )
   {
       this.props.router.push(`/page2`);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `this.props.router.push(/page2)` after success of `fetchTweets(param1,param2)` network call.

Or you can use promise , and use `this.props.router.push(`/page2`);` in success of that promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the router as parameter to the action. I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it should work.

```
toPageTwo() {
      this.fetchTweets(param1,param2,  this.props.router);
    }
}



export function fetchTweets(a,b, router){
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/?a="+a+"&b="+b)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_FULFILLED", payload: response.data});
            router.push('/page2')
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_REJECTED", payload: err})
        })
    }
}
```